# How can I find a matching ID to an anchor onClick using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react app and I have a few on page anchors. I've made divs with the proper IDs and the traditional anchor tag with a hash matching those IDs.

How can I find the same div ID when I click on the anchor with the matching hash? Right now I'm using the `event` to pass into my `onClick` function.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What is a click on the `<a>` supposed to do? Scroll to the div? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: The click on the anchor will scroll to that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to provide the `id` in your `onClick` handler in the jsx.

```
<a onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)}>{id}</a>
```

Comment: What if the my markup looks like this: `<a onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)}>Some Text</a>`

Comment: That should work find so long as the `id` variable is available